# DateTime.Now value is changing

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to use the a current timestamp as an identifier for some data.

Executing the following code will result in a different timestamp (+50ms )with each execution even though **timestamp** is assigned before the For Each

```
Dim timestamp = DateTime.Now
For Each x In y
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Foo(data, timestamp)
Next
```

```
Sub Foo(data As Dat, timestamp As Date) 
  Dim con As New SqlConnection
  con.ConnectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TopSecret").ConnectionString
  Dim cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand
  con.Open()
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  cmd.CommandText = "spX"
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", data))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Timestamp", timestamp))
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

But 2nd snippet below will print the identical time every time - and I believe that's the [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-6.0) behavior.

Why does it behave different here?

```
Dim timestamp = DateTime.Now
For i As Integer = 0 To 3
  str += timestamp .ToString + vbNewLine
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
Next
```

Comment: can you share some value output by the first method?

Comment: @DrewAguirre  this is what the timestamp column looks in my SQL table https://ibb.co/gRZtkw1

Comment: put a debug.writeline of the timestamp in the foo function, somehting wierd is happening

Comment: Good call, it looks like as soon as Foo() receives the date parameter it defaults its value to "1/1/0001" (even though I pass the same data type). Thanks for putting me on the right track

Comment: Their is something weird here alright.  Shouldn't be changing.  That aside though, if your goal is a record timestamp in your database, why even do this via vb.  Much more robust to deal with it in SQL server.  You can use either a TimeStamp column or a DateTime with the default value set

Comment: Do you get the same effect if you call System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50) AFTER calling Foo() ?